# Tiles 2.2.1 configuration

Tags: apache, jsp, configuration, tiles2

I have used Tiles 2.1, but in version 2.2 configuration has changed, but sadly their documentation seems to be very confusing*, at least for me. And their example project download link is not working.

- http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

[Tiles 2.2.2 Sample Application Source Code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tiles/framework/tags/tiles-2.2.2/) (download the module named **tiles-test-pom**).